# Android 4.4.2 crash during picking image

Tags: android, xamarin, crash, android-4.4-kitkat

During developing application in Xamarin Android we encountered strange error. The pick image/video (whether its from camera or documents UI) application sometimes crashes with no error. Scenario is that we open application, make steps to the activity, where the images are chosen, and then open the camera or document UI by standard way:

```
    public void ChooseMediaAfterTypeChose (bool photo, bool camera) {
        try {
            string title = "";
            int id;

            Intent iIntent;

            if (camera) {
                if (photo) {
                    iIntent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
                    id = Const.AND_pickImageID_camera;
                    App._file = new File (App._dir, "myPhoto.jpg");
                    iIntent.PutExtra (Android.Provider.MediaStore.ExtraOutput, Uri.FromFile (App._file));
                } else {
                    iIntent = new Intent("android.media.action.VIDEO_CAPTURE");
                    id = Const.AND_pickVideoID_camera;

                    App._file = new File (App._dir, "myVideo.mp4");
                    iIntent.PutExtra (Android.Provider.MediaStore.ExtraOutput, Uri.FromFile (App._file));
                }
            } else {
                iIntent = new Intent ();
                iIntent.SetAction (Intent.ActionGetContent);
                if (photo) {
                    iIntent.SetType ("image/jpg");
                    title = Static.mainData.currentTexts.ChoosePhoto;
                    id = Const.AND_pickImageID_galery;
                } else {
                    iIntent.SetType ("video/mp4");
                    title = Static.mainData.currentTexts.ChooseVideo;
                    id = Const.AND_pickVideoID_galery;
                }
            }

            if (camera) {
                StartActivityForResult (iIntent, id);
            } else {
                StartActivityForResult (Intent.CreateChooser (iIntent, title), id);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ShowError (Static.mainData.currentTexts.MediaError);
            W.L(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

The chosen application crashes during image/video picking (E.g. during browsing images in gallery wthout picking any). When that happens we never get to any method in our code.

What we have:

1. When user don't pick photos, the application runs without any memory crash
2. Sometimes the picking proceedes without error.
3. We think that the issue is mainly on Android 4.4.2 (It happend to us only on devices with this android - on other android version devices we didn't encounter it)

What we tried:

1. We put all permissions to manifest (read/write external storage, hardware.camera etc.)
2. We delete almost all memory stored content to save up memory
3. All Activities are unload from memory when they leave the screen
4. Logcat says that every process connected (Application and the active application) just died with no trace to any error

Our question is if anyone stumbled to similar issue and how to handle it. The second question is if there is any way to find out whats happening.

EDIT:

App._dir code added.

```
        App._dir = new Java.IO.File (
            Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory (
                Environment.DirectoryPictures), "Camera");
        if (!App._dir.Exists ())
        {
            App._dir.Mkdirs( );
        }
```

Comment: it happens with every image despite the image size? what is the App._dir path?

Comment: It happens before choosing any image. App._dir code added.

Comment: sorry im still not sure whn it happens, in which line usually crash?

Comment: No info. All lines from 1st code are executed and the pick application is launched. Then in random moment the pick application crashes with our application.

Comment: the memory usage when the crash is happening is random?

Comment: Yes it is random - one device have 75% used some device has 35% used.